# How to UITextView text content come to start from the top

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using the code below in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

set the content offset in viewDidLayoutSubviews for it to take effect

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.yourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```